# Vue 2 : Cannot read property id of null

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I'm having a list of orders, where each of them is clickable to view the orderdetails.

I have used hours of debugging to try understanding why the id property is null at the landing page, but looks fine through the store, and api call functions.

The best way to describe this is through code, so take a look (See the comments where the ID still has a valid value).

**-> WORKING ROUTE**

```
 { path: '/vieworder/:id', component: ViewOrder, props: true },
```

**-> ROUTE PUSH TO DETAILS PAGE :**

```
methods: {
        ...mapActions(['getOrders']),
        init() {
            this.getOrders()
        },
        viewOrder: function(order){
            this.$router.push('/vieworder/' + order.id)
        }
    },
```

**-> VIEWORDER.VUE  (ID IS NULL IN TEMPLATE..)**

```js
    import * as types from '../store/mutationtypes'
    import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        name: 'ViewOrder',
        props: {
            id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.$store.dispatch('getOrderById', {
                id: this.id
            })
            console.log('The id is now : ' + this.id)
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(["order"])
        }
    }
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <h4>{{ order.id }}</h4>
    </div>
</template>
```

**--> STORE AND GETORDERBYID (ID VALUE IS CORRECT HERE...)**

```
export default new Vuex.Store({ 
state: {
    orders: [],
    order: null
},
getters: {
    orders: state => state.orders,
    order: state => state.order
},
actions: {
    getOrders({ commit }) {
        api.getOrders().then(orders => commit(types.UPDATE_ORDERS, orders))
    },
    getOrderById({ commit }, { id }){
        console.log("In Store now - Do we have an id ? : " + id)
        api.getOrderById(id).then(order => commit(types.UPDATE_ORDER, order))
    }, 
    etc.etc.etc...
```

**--> API CALL RETURNING DATA**

```
getOrderById(orderId){
    return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/Orders/' + orderId)
 .then(response => response.data)   
},
```

**--> EXAMPLE DATA RETURNED FROM API CALL**

```
"Orders": [
{
  "id": 123456,
  "PaidDate": "2017-01-12",
  "AppId": "KLM-UXI-NIX-FIX",
  "TicketType": "Barn - Enkeltbillett",
  "TicketCount": 1,
  "OrderSum": "17",
  "MediaChannel": "Android",
  "StatusCode": "08-12-34-56-78",
  "PaymentOption": "VISA"
},
```

**--> ERROR**
[image]

Comment: Dont use `getOrderById({ commit }, { id })` since you are already using id from object use, `getOrderById({ commit }, id)`

Comment: wow!.. that was a quick commend @AmreshVenugopal :) So this might be the reason for my programming-headache ? 

I'll try that out riiight now.. I'll get back to you very shortly...

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal : by changing as you suggested, i'm receiving : GET http://localhost:3000/Orders/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: In VIEWORDER.VUE you should probably use `mounted()` instead of `created()`. If it doesn't solve the issue, do in `mounted()` hook: `this.id = this.$route.params.id`

Comment: @wostex : i'll give it a try right away.. be right back.

Comment: @wostex : modified to : mounted() {
            this.id = this.$route.params.id,
            this.$store.dispatch('getOrderById', {
                
                id: this.id
            })
            console.log('The id is now : ' + this.id)
        },

But no change i'm afraid.. seems like the object "order" doesn't exist ?

Comment: @wostex : this is really weird.. if i remove the line : <h4>{{ order.id }}</h4>, and refreshes i have no errors (since i'm not using any of the data).. If i paste the line in again, it's displaying the id correctly and it seems to be working... BUT : If i refresh the browser again... i'm back with the same error, and have to remove the line again to make it work..

Comment: You can try to change `getOrderById({ commit }, { id })` to `getOrderById({ commit }, id)` in vuex and call it as `this.$store.dispatch('getOrderById', id)` in mounted() hook, if the order is empty. Also you can check if the order exists like this `<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" v-if="order.id">` to avoid errors before data is fetched.

Comment: Great !!.. That actually seemed to fix the issue here.. Not that i understand _why_.. I also updated vue and all dependencies to newest version, and that eliminated atleast one vue warn i was struggling with.

Can you post this as an answer instead of a comment since i'ts the right solution so i can accept it ?

Comment: @TerjeNygård The reason you get the error is because `order` is populated in the store asynchronously. Meaning, `order` is `null` when the component is mounted. Your template uses `order.id`, which, when it is *first* rendered is basically `null.id` which is invalid. Later, when your `getOrderById` ajax call completes, order *has* a value.  Wostex suggestion to use `v-if` prevents the component from trying to access `order.id` until `order` actually has a value.

Comment: @TerjeNygård, glad it helped. I've reposted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change `getOrderById({ commit }, { id })` to `getOrderById({ commit }, id)` in vuex and call it as `this.$store.dispatch('getOrderById', id)` in `mounted()` hook, if the order is empty.

Also you can check if the order exists like this `<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" v-if="order.id">` to avoid errors before data is fetched.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to OP's specific situation, but to the title of the question. I had the same console error message from vuejs "Cannot read property id of null" or "Cannot read property id of undefined".

I eventually solved it by going through all my code and making sure every usage of "x.id" is inside a block like "if (x)".  For example, if "x" is set in "props" of the vue component, it looks like the following can fail with "Cannot read property id of undefined":

```
<div v-for="y in x" :key="y.id">
  {{ y.name }}
</div>
```

The solution was to wrap it in a `v-if` block like this:

```
<div v-if="x">
  <div v-for="y in x" :key="y.id">
    {{ y.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Similarly, in a computed property, it looks like the following can fail:

```
computed: {
  sumids: function () {
    var finalsum = 0
    for (var y of this.x) {
      finalsum += y.id
    }
    return finalsum
  }
},
```

The solution was to wrap it in an `if` block like this:

```
computed: {
  sumids: function () {
    var finalsum = 0
    if (this.x) {
      for (var y of this.x) {
        finalsum += y.id
      }
    }
    return finalsum
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional and useful comment @krubo :)